# Anonymously vandalized posts

Tags: support

I have noticed several edits made to various OP's comments and/or questions that were complete garbage.  In particular, it seems that some virus or virus like program keeps changing various perfectly valid posts, turning them into links to potentially harmful websites.  Fortunately, the moderator tools have been able to catch a number of them, but I'm not sure if all have been accounted for.  They seem to be eminating from an anonymous user, which is completely bizarre to me... I thought all users have to register in order to use the site, much less edit it.

If you happen to notice any posts suddenly changed to suspicious looking links, please do not click on them and flag them right away.

Answer (score 4):

There've been five of these so far from the same IP address, all rejected (thankfully!)

Please do report these if you encounter them in the future - if it becomes a significant problem, we'll do our best to block them.

**Update:** it turned out that there were a couple hundred cases of abuse network-wide. We've blocked the IP.